# Find and get a string from two other strings?

Tags: java, string

I want to look for a String within another String in JAVA. Then gets its location.
I wanted to crop things before and after the string im searching for.

```
String Str1 = "Cats";
String Str2 = "Bear";
String Str3 = "MonkeysDogsCatsPandasPolarBear";
```

So it would print *"PandasPolar"*

Comment: Which programming language? Pseudo-algorithm?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the programming language you intend to use!!

Comment: You need a `substring`. Many languages provide both `string.Substring()` as well as `string.IndexOf()` to get the character position of that occurrence.

Comment: @OnlineCop Why does one "need" substring? ;-)

Comment: @OnlineCop lol, or `Mid` in VB and `strncpy` in C!

Comment: Im a noob at monogramming, and im programming in java

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Regular expression :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String str3 = "MonkeysDogsCatsPandasPolarBear";
String str1 = "Cats";
String str2 = "Bear";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=" + str1 + ")(.*?)(?=" + str2 + ")");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str3);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**output :**

> PandasPolar

Comment: The OP can hardly programm and you are suggesting using regex.  Tears before bedtime.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood Actually, this is basically the way i use to learn, i'd prefer to see some new solutions for a same problem (how hard they looks). Regex is quite a big part but it's pretty useful.

Answer (score -1):

simplest/easiest way would be :

```
System.out.print(Str3.substring(Str3.indexOf(Str1) + Str1.length(), Str3.indexOf(Str2)));
```

But **Not Advised** as it could throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` due to the use if `.indexOf()`..

To avoid this exception, you could use a `try{ } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){ }`, or you could check if both strings exits in the main string before extracting the custom phrase, here's how to do both..

Catching the exception :

```
try{
    System.out.println(str3.substring(str3.indexOf(str1) + str1.length(), str3.indexOf(str2)));
}catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
    System.out.println("string Not Found!");
}
```

Check before extract :

```
if(str3.indexOf(str1) == -1 || str3.indexOf(str2) == -1) System.out.println("Not Found!");
else System.out.println(str3.substring(str3.indexOf(str1) + str1.length(), str3.indexOf(str2)));
```

Get detailed message of what was not exactly found :

```
if(str3.indexOf(str1) == -1) System.out.println(str1 + " Was not found in " + str3);
else if(str3.indexOf(str2) == -1) System.out.println(str2 + " Was not found in " + str3);
else System.out.println(str3.substring(str3.indexOf(str1) + str1.length(), str3.indexOf(str2)));
```

Read about String `substring()` Method [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm), and String `indexOf()` Method [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm)

Comment: bound to end up throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException `  best to check values returned by indexof

Comment: An expanded answer with index checking would be better than just saying `Not Advised`  - How about giving something that is advised.